# gedit weird encoding of standard text file

Tags: gedit, encoding

This question wa also posted in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610705/gedit-weird-encoding-of-standard-text-file).

I have a standard text file that is shown perfect with cat:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
v0[shape = Mrecord, label = ""]
```

When I use xxd to examine the exact line ending I get this:

```
$ xxd myfile.txt
00000000: 7630 5b73 6861 7065 203d 204d 7265 636f  v0[shape = Mreco
00000010: 7264 2c20 6c61 6265 6c20 3d20 2222 5d0a  rd, label = ""].
```

However when I try to open it with gedit, I get a weird encoding of some non Latin language.
What goes wrong in gedit?
Here is the complete source code for reproducing:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ofstream myfile("myfile.txt");
    myfile << "v0[shape = Mrecord, label = \"\"]\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my compilation line:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

In addition, I'm attaching the image file of the the gedit screen:

[image]

**EDIT**: (output from suggested remarks)

```
$ gedit --list-encodings | grep -Fx UTF-8
UTF-8
$ gedit --encoding UTF-8 myfile.txt
$ file -bi myfile.txt
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Comment: Just to get it right: When you open `myfile.txt` in `gedit` it just shows those asian characters instead of `v0[shape = Mrecord, label = ""]`? For me it works, btw (with `myfile.txt` created by your C++ program). What does `file myfile.txt` show?

Comment: pretty sure it's a language issue, it's inside the *Tools* menu, *Defined language*, just select English

Comment: @PerlDuck yes, when I open myfile.txt it shows those Asian characters instead of what it should. I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 with the default gedit shipped.

Comment: @damadam English was already highlighted as the chosen language.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom 17.10 is **EOL**

Comment: Can you try using `gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.encodings auto-detected "['UTF-8', 'GBK', 'CURRENT', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"`

Comment: Does `gedit --list-encodings | grep -Fx UTF-8` give `UTF-8`? If so, does `gedit --encoding UTF-8 myfile.txt` give the proper result? What is the output of `file -bi myfile.txt`? If this is not `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` then there is something strange about your magic(5). In that case, check that there is no file `~/.magic` and that no environment variable `MAGIC` is set, and whether there are any files in `/usr/share/misc/magic`.

Comment: Updated post to contain suggestions -- the command `gedit --encoding UTF-8 myfile.txt` has no output, is that OK?

Comment: Have you tried other text editors? Sublime text or Kate or...

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny yes, it works perfect in vim (that is, I see what I expect, v0 ...)

Comment: In case of weird behaviour of just one program I would consider checking their bug tracker and creating issue if none matches (even if closed as "not a bug" maybe it would reveal what is wrong).

Comment: Take a look at the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.gedit` and see if anything stands out... Also look at the full output of `gedit --list-encodings`, it's possible that UTF-16 is earlier than UTF-8 and so it's trying to interpret the file that way... It looks like it's using some kind of UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE, though it could be some other kind of Unicode encoding... I hope these hints can help you debug this! Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the encoding to UTF-8 when you launch the gedit, e.g.,

```
\gedit --encoding UTF-8 myfile.txt
```

Somewhere you have the default encoding set to UTF-16LE as indicated by @filipe-brandenburger. You can verify this by using the UTF-16LE encoding to see the weird output.

```
\gedit --encoding UTF-16LE myfile.txt
```

Update -- encoding may be stored with the file uri.

Gnome editor apparently cached the encoding type along with the file uri. You can see this my moving the file around. E.g.,

```
echo "Hello there." > testfile.txt
\gedit --encoding UTF-16LE testfile.txt
```

*(see Chinese text)*

```
mkdir tempdir
mv testfile.txt tempdir
cd tempdir
\gedit --encoding UTF-8 testfile.txt
```

*(English text)*

Now open without specifying encoding.

```
\gedit testfile.txt
```

*(English text)*

But moving the file back cause it to use a different encoding.

```
mv testfile.txt ..
cd ..
\gedit testfile.txt
```

*(see Chinese text)*

Comment: Why are you putting  a backslash in front of `gedit`? it should run fine without the backslash.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I added the backslash just in case there is an alias for gedit. The backslash remove any alias for it.